# How to let the user add 'None' to an specific array that's is set as value of an specific key in a dictionary on Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, for-loop

Ok so, the question may sound confusing at first but I'm gonna do my best to explain what I would like to learn in order to improve my programming skills.

Let's say I have a path in which exists 6 folders with the following file images:

#### Color:

> Amarillo.png Blanco.png Rojirosado.png Turquesa.png Verde_oscuro.png Zapote.png

#### Cuerpo:

> Cuerpo_cangrejo.png

#### Fondo:

> Oceano.png

#### Ojos:

> Antenas.png Pico.png Verticales.png

#### Pinzas:

> Pinzitas.png Pinzotas.png Pinzota_pinzita.png

#### Puas:

> Arena.png Marron.png Purpura.png Verde.png

Now, I want the above information to be stored in a dictionary for further use, so I run the code below **in the same path in which the folders previously mentioned exist**:

```
import os
# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}

for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

**So after compiling the program above I get my dictionary:**

[image: Dictionary]

But here's the problem: After creating the dictionary, how can I let the user decide in which arrays to add a '**None**' string as a new value (i.e. not replacing the current ones), meaning that, for instance, if the user wanted to add '**None**' only to `Puas` Array and `Pinzas` Array, it would generate the following output?:

```
the_dictionary_list: {
'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png','Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 
'Zapote.png'],
'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'],
'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 
'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'],
'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Comment: How are you getting user input to know in which list to add the None? If you know the key of the list that needs updating, you could write `the_dictionary_list['whatever_key_that_needs_updating'].insert(0, 'None')`. Or if that None doesn't need to be in the first position, better to use `the_dictionary_list['whatever_key_that_needs_updating'].append('None')`

Comment: @robbo the program above would first print ```the_dictionary_list first (initial one)``` , informing the user which are the keys and the values (arrays) such dictionary has. That would let the user decide in which key to add the 'None' value in the array.

Comment: Ok so then you can update the dictionary using the commands mentioned above, using the actual key instead of the whatever_key_that_needs_updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can interpret, you would like to get the user input and insert `None` to the front of each of those keys. As @robbo mentions, you can use insert. A text implementation of this would look like:

```
to_add = []
user_input = input("Which directory to add None to: ")

# Will exit when user gives null input
while user_input:
    if user_input in the_dictionary_list:
        to_add.append(user_input)
    else:
        print("Try again.")
    user_input = input("Which directory to add None to: ")

# Add to dictionary
for key in to_add:
    the_dictionary_list[key].insert(0, None)
```